# Function field for many2many odoo 8

Tags: function, many-to-many, field, odoo-8

I need to declare a `many2many` field as functional field. I tried below code but doesn't create any relational table in database.

```
def _get_function(self,cr,uid,ids,name,args,context=None):
    resp={}
    for data in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):
        print'inside get Function'
    return resp

'many2many_ids': fields.function(_get_function, method=True, relation="table.table1", obj='table1_table2_rel', type="many2many" , string="Many2Many")
```

Now data saved in form view, but i can't access that values in another function. like,

```
 for data in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):
        print'many2many_ids',data.many2many_ids
```

Here print no values.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the field to be stored use "store" option.

Also, you might consider using new API on v8. Check "Computed field" in official docs https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html

Comment: when i use store = True i getting an error:   File "/home/kabeer/git/liveAMS/openerp/models.py", line 2633, in _auto_init
    cr.execute('ALTER TABLE "%s" ADD COLUMN "%s" %s' % (self._table, k, get_pg_type(f)[1]))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'